# Similar content on multiple pages. How does this impact SEO?

Tags: seo

I recently posted a question about using a site structure similar to what's shown below.

```
example.com/bikes/foo-bike/wheels    //content about foo-bike's wheels
example.com/bikes/bar-bike/wheels    //content about bar-bike's wheels
```

If two bikes are at comparable price points, it's likely that they will have similar components. Should I be concerned if multiple bikes have similar content and the only major difference between them is their component name?

The website I'm creating is a user guide for bikes. With the URL structure above I'm a little worried that I run the risk for creating duplicate content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can 'dilute duplicate' content by adding unique content around it.  What I might do here is add a unique description for each bike if possible. Even if they are similar, but slightly different you should probably be able to create an interesting, unique description.

Say for example that one bike is more geared towards beginners, but the other one is more for experienced riders.

some thing like:

> The big brother to the Foo-Bike, the Bar-Bike uses the same perfect
>   frame geometry, but comes with an extra inch of travel up front so you
>   can suck up those drops with ease. As the gear set in the Foo-Bike is
>   probably the best around, we use the same setup on the Bar-Bike, but
>   we have added a bashguard to the bottom of the chain disc to ensure
>   you never get hooked up while hurtling down the trails. We have also
>   kept the same top of the range wheelset, as is featured on the
>   Foo-Bike, simply coating them in extra wide Nooby tires to ensure you
>   always stick to the trail, however fast you are gunning it!

If you're adding a unique description like that (and one on the other bikes page), then you can list out the components specs of the bikes, without really worrying about duplicate content across the pages.